# How to put a Json respose in hashmap

Tags: java, android, json, dictionary, hash

hi everyone i really need you help for this one
i'm getting this json response using get request with retrofit :

```
 [{
"id": 2,
"name": "admin",
"password_last_update": null,
"phone": "2516512",
"phone2": null,
"mobile": null,
"realname": "zizo",
"firstname": null,
"locations_id": 0,
"language": null,
"use_mode": 0,
"list_limit": 20,
"is_active": 1,
"comment": null,
"auths_id": 0,
"authtype": 1,
"last_login": "2021-06-14 17:36:58",
"date_mod": "2021-06-14 16:29:50",
"date_sync": null,
"is_deleted": 0,
"profiles_id": 0,
"entities_id": 0,
"usertitles_id": 0,
"usercategories_id": 0,
"date_format": null,
"number_format": null,
"names_format": null,
"csv_delimiter": null,
"is_ids_visible": null,
"use_flat_dropdowntree": null,
"show_jobs_at_login": null,
"priority_1": null,
"priority_2": null,
"priority_3": null,
"priority_4": null,
"priority_5": null,
"priority_6": null,
"followup_private": null,
"task_private": null,
"default_requesttypes_id": null,
"password_forget_token": null,
"password_forget_token_date": null,
"user_dn": null,
"registration_number": null,
"show_count_on_tabs": null,
"refresh_views": null,
"set_default_tech": null,
"personal_token_date": null,
"api_token_date": null,
"cookie_token_date": "2021-06-14 16:29:50",
"display_count_on_home": null,
"notification_to_myself": null,
"duedateok_color": null,
"duedatewarning_color": null,
"duedatecritical_color": null,
"duedatewarning_less": null,
"duedatecritical_less": null,
"duedatewarning_unit": null,
"duedatecritical_unit": null,
"display_options": null,
"is_deleted_ldap": 0,
"pdffont": null,
"picture": null,
"begin_date": null,
"end_date": null,
"keep_devices_when_purging_item": null,
"privatebookmarkorder": null,
"backcreated": null,
"task_state": null,
"layout": null,
"palette": null,
"set_default_requester": null,
"lock_autolock_mode": null,
"lock_directunlock_notification": null,
"date_creation": null,
"highcontrast_css": null,
"plannings": null,
"sync_field": null,
"groups_id": 0,
"users_id_supervisor": 0,
"timezone": null,
"default_dashboard_central": null,
"default_dashboard_assets": null,
"default_dashboard_helpdesk": null,
"default_dashboard_mini_ticket": null,
"links": [
  {
    "rel": "Entity",
    "href": "https://aziz.with7.glpi-network.cloud/apirest.php/Entity/0"
  },
  {
    "rel": "Document_Item",
    "href": "https://aziz.with7.glpi-network.cloud/apirest.php/User/2/Document_Item/"
  }
  ]
  },
   {
   "id": 6,
   "name": "aziz",
"password_last_update": "2021-05-31 12:01:43",
"phone": "",
"phone2": "",
"mobile": "",
"realname": "aziz",
"firstname": "",
"locations_id": 0,
"language": null,
"use_mode": 0,
"list_limit": null,
"is_active": 1,
"comment": "",
"auths_id": 0,
"authtype": 1,
"last_login": "2021-06-14 16:48:52",
"date_mod": "2021-06-14 16:48:52",
"date_sync": null,
"is_deleted": 0,
"profiles_id": 0,
"entities_id": 0,
"usertitles_id": 0,
"usercategories_id": 0,
"date_format": null,
"number_format": null,
"names_format": null,
"csv_delimiter": null,
"is_ids_visible": null,
"use_flat_dropdowntree": null,
"show_jobs_at_login": null,
"priority_1": null,
"priority_2": null,
"priority_3": null,
"priority_4": null,
"priority_5": null,
"priority_6": null,
"followup_private": null,
"task_private": null,
"default_requesttypes_id": null,
"password_forget_token": null,
"password_forget_token_date": null,
"user_dn": null,
"registration_number": "",
"show_count_on_tabs": null,
"refresh_views": null,
"set_default_tech": null,
"personal_token_date": null,
"api_token_date": null,
"cookie_token_date": "2021-06-14 16:48:52",
"display_count_on_home": null,
"notification_to_myself": null,
"duedateok_color": null,
"duedatewarning_color": null,
"duedatecritical_color": null,
"duedatewarning_less": null,
"duedatecritical_less": null,
"duedatewarning_unit": null,
"duedatecritical_unit": null,
"display_options": null,
"is_deleted_ldap": 0,
"pdffont": null,
"picture": "f7/6_60c3e5d2a69f7.jpg",
"begin_date": null,
"end_date": null,
"keep_devices_when_purging_item": null,
"privatebookmarkorder": null,
"backcreated": null,
"task_state": null,
"layout": null,
"palette": null,
"set_default_requester": null,
"lock_autolock_mode": null,
"lock_directunlock_notification": null,
"date_creation": "2021-05-31 12:01:43",
"highcontrast_css": null,
"plannings": null,
"sync_field": null,
"groups_id": 0,
"users_id_supervisor": 0,
"timezone": null,
"default_dashboard_central": null,
"default_dashboard_assets": null,
"default_dashboard_helpdesk": null,
"default_dashboard_mini_ticket": null,
"links": [
  {
    "rel": "Entity",
    "href": "https://aziz.with7.glpi-network.cloud/apirest.php/Entity/0"
  },
  {
    "rel": "Document_Item",
    "href": "https://aziz.with7.glpi-network.cloud/apirest.php/User/6/Document_Item/"
  }
]
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "kaso",
"password_last_update": "2021-06-08 00:12:10",
"phone": "",
"phone2": "",
"mobile": "",
"realname": "ben Haj Laroussi",
"firstname": "Mohamed Aziz",
"locations_id": 0,
"language": null,
"use_mode": 0,
"list_limit": null,
"is_active": 1,
"comment": "",
"auths_id": 0,
"authtype": 1,
"last_login": "2021-06-13 17:18:45",
"date_mod": "2021-06-12 01:32:23",
"date_sync": null,
"is_deleted": 0,
"profiles_id": 0,
"entities_id": 0,
"usertitles_id": 0,
"usercategories_id": 0,
"date_format": null,
"number_format": null,
"names_format": null,
"csv_delimiter": null,
"is_ids_visible": null,
"use_flat_dropdowntree": null,
"show_jobs_at_login": null,
"priority_1": null,
"priority_2": null,
"priority_3": null,
"priority_4": null,
"priority_5": null,
"priority_6": null,
"followup_private": null,
"task_private": null,
"default_requesttypes_id": null,
"password_forget_token": null,
"password_forget_token_date": null,
"user_dn": null,
"registration_number": "",
"show_count_on_tabs": null,
"refresh_views": null,
"set_default_tech": null,
"personal_token_date": null,
"api_token_date": null,
"cookie_token_date": "2021-06-08 00:18:05",
"display_count_on_home": null,
"notification_to_myself": null,
"duedateok_color": null,
"duedatewarning_color": null,
"duedatecritical_color": null,
"duedatewarning_less": null,
"duedatecritical_less": null,
"duedatewarning_unit": null,
"duedatecritical_unit": null,
"display_options": null,
"is_deleted_ldap": 0,
"pdffont": null,
"picture": null,
"begin_date": null,
"end_date": null,
"keep_devices_when_purging_item": null,
"privatebookmarkorder": null,
"backcreated": null,
"task_state": null,
"layout": null,
"palette": null,
"set_default_requester": null,
"lock_autolock_mode": null,
"lock_directunlock_notification": null,
"date_creation": "2021-06-08 00:12:10",
"highcontrast_css": null,
"plannings": null,
"sync_field": null,
"groups_id": 0,
"users_id_supervisor": 0,
"timezone": null,
"default_dashboard_central": null,
"default_dashboard_assets": null,
"default_dashboard_helpdesk": null,
"default_dashboard_mini_ticket": null,
"links": [
  {
    "rel": "Entity",
    "href": "https://aziz.with7.glpi-network.cloud/apirest.php/Entity/0"
  },
  {
    "rel": "Document_Item",
    "href": "https://aziz.with7.glpi-network.cloud/apirest.php/User/7/Document_Item/"
  }
]
}
]
```

i'm using this code to get the data and to put it in a List :

```
    Retrofit retrofit= RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
    final Api api= retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<List<User>> call = api.getUser(sestoken);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {

            if (response.code() != 200){
                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: something is wrong"+response.code() );



            }
            List<User> users = response.body();



            for (User user : users){

                userList.add(user);
            }

            



           

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {


        }
    });
```

and this is the user class
package model;

```
public class User {

private String name;
private String id;


public String getName() { return name; }

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}

i only need to put the id and name in a hashmap i really didn't know how to do it i could only put the data in a list . appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that user id's are unique, you can create a simple HashMap with **user id** as the **Key** and **user name** as the **Value**.

```
Map<Integer, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();

for (User user : users) {
    if (userMap.get(user.getId()) == null)
        userMap.put(user.getId(), user.getName());
}

System.out.println("userMap : " + userMap);
```

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as "Accepted" so that it can be of help to others.